# Highlight expanded comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface, information-display, highlighting

It'd be nice to somehow distinguish comments that were expanded from those that were shown by default.

Sometimes I'll read the first few comments which have been voted up and then hit expand to show remaining comments (some of which might also be voted up, just less I guess). Once expanded, it's not obvious which ones I've already read and I pretty much have to rescan the entire list.

This is similar to the old MS Office menus which would initially show recently used options but after a delay would show all options.

Some unobtrusive highlighting or bordering or something--maybe just a dash in the number of votes position or something tiny and subtle...

Comment: What's with the love of the Office menus? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9467/show-more-comments-should-add-comments-at-the-bottom-not-just-show-all-chronol

Comment: No, that wasn't meant to be a dupe but it's on a similar track.

Comment: I had not seen that question--it's just such a similar (and annoying) user experience, I guess

Comment: btw: in case it isn't clear to others--I'm not suggesting that the old office menu approach is good; in fact, I consider it a UI failure