# Highlight additional comments after clicking "show n more comments"

Tags: feature-request, comments

Stack Exchange hides some comments (low votes etc.), and displays a "Show n more comments" link to reveal them.

When they are revealed it can be difficult to determine which are the new comments that have just been displayed. They should be highlighted in some fashion (probably with a darker background) to indicate they were previously hidden.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21589/highlight-expanded-comments and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24490/can-we-get-an-indication-comments-are-hidden-between-the-comments which has been highly-voted on, but finally declined. I like the idea though and do second it.