# Disjointed comment threads ("Add/show more comments")

Tags: feature-request, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get an indication comments are hidden between the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24490/can-we-get-an-indication-comments-are-hidden-between-the-comments)

When a post gets too many comments, the link "Add/show more comments" appears. That's ok, but the problem is, that this can lead to disjointed comment threads: Assume the following comments:

```
        Votes   Comment
```

```
            1   Comment1 - userX
            1   Comment2 - userY
            1   I think userX is correct. - userA
                @userA: I agree 100%. - userB
                @userB: But userY also has a good point. - userA
            1   @userA: I don't think so. - userB
            1   @userB: Comment7 - userA
```

But if the comments are folded, it appears as:

```
        Votes   Comment
```

```
            1   Comment1 - userX
            1   Comment2 - userY
            1   I think userX is correct. - userA
            1   @userA: I don't think so. - userB
            1   @userB: Comment7 - userA
```

So, Comment 4 and 5 are missing. That's also ok, but it would be great, if there was **some kind of separator** - maybe an ellipsis **(…)** - between Comment 3 and Comment 6.

Since the "Add/show more comments" link can easily be scrolled out of view (and it looks almost exactly the same as the "Add comment" link), this can lead to some confusion.

**Edit:**

I'd like to point you to [Can we get an indication comments are hidden between the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24490/can-we-get-an-indication-comments-are-hidden-between-the-comments) (this was found by AnonJr). Vote over there!

Comment: Have you seen any users that are confused enough to comment on it?  (Were you really confused and *couldn't* figure it out?  Doesn't seem so from the question.)  I imagine 99% of users figure it out pretty quickly that 'show more comments' displays the full in-order history.

Comment: I always figure it out, after I'm confused. But I don't feel, that this provides a good user experience.

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9467/show-more-comments-should-add-comments-at-the-bottom-not-just-show-all-chronol

Comment: And also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24490/can-we-get-an-indication-comments-are-hidden-between-the-comments

Comment: @Anon: Yep, I'd even say that one's a dupe.

Comment: @AnonJr: Thanks for this link! It's good that I'm not the only one with this problem.