# An option to show all comments by default?

Tags: feature-request, comments, preferences

I'd really like to have the option to show all comments by default to questions and answers, instead of having to click on "show more comments" each time.

This would be really helpful where there are long discussions following a question or an answer (like here on Meta), because reading them in chronological order makes *a lot more sense* than reading only the most voted ones.

Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps it could auto-expand if the total amount of comments on the whole question is below a certain threshold? I wouldn't want this to happen on EVERY question, since some might contain comment wars in which case the current implementation is much better.

Comment: Totally agree: I don't see the point of hiding one or two comments and making me click on show more.  How does that help me?  I'm ok with not showing all comments, but perhaps if it is like 25 or more!!

Comment: A user script to automatically expand all comments: https://stackapps.com/questions/7993/expand-all-comments-script

Answer (score 5):

There was discussion of a comment expansion user preference, [back when comment voting was introduced](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-now-with-flags-and-votes/), but nobody seemed that interested in it -- so we haven't followed up.

Comment: Any plan on trying again?

Comment: Here here... Seconded...

Comment: It would be great!

Comment: Please do. A part of the problem is that comments are hidden based on points (or whatever), so after reading some of them and clicking on "show all" you're lost. I see I'm not the first one [complaining about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9467/show-more-comments-should-add-comments-at-the-bottom-not-just-show-all-chronol/21596#21596).